# Sort Alphanumeric values in T-SQL ,SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting

Hi I have values like this in my field name called "**NumberName**"

```
AB1
CD2
XH506
PQ104
PZ77
```

**I am trying to order this** so far I have tried is:

```
select * from view_name where NumberName='Something' 
order by RIGHT('0000' + SUBSTRING(NumberName, ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',NumberName), 0), 
LEN(NumberName)+1), LEN(NumberName)), 4)
```

**and**

```
order by LEN(NumberName),NumberName
```

how to achieve this..?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from yourtable
order by LEFT(columnname,1)
```

Comment: @Vijesh -- This query will not help you to achieve what you are trying to?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, I didn't fully understand your question. But `ORDER BY NumberName` correctly sorts the values.

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(NumberName NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @temp (NumberName)
VALUES ('AB1'),('CD2'),('XH506'),('PQ104'),('PZ77')

SELECT *
FROM @temp
ORDER BY NumberName
```

**Output:**

```
NumberName
----------
AB1
CD2
PQ104
PZ77
XH506
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain this well enough, but I recon you'd like to sort the result based on value of rightmost number. Try this. You need to first find first occurence of not-a-number form the right, to know where the last number begins (`PATINDEX('%[0-9]%` will give you first number, but in "FB3C2" for example numbers are mixed with letters).

```
select 
    * 
    ,right(NumberName,PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',reverse(NumberName))-1)
from (
    select 'ABC001' as numbername union all
    select 'XQ20001' union all
    select 'XQ20002' union all
    select 'XQ20003' union all
    select 'XQ20004' union all
    select 'PM130010' union all
    select 'PM130011' union all
    select 'PM130012' union all
    select 'PM130013' union all
    select 'PM130014' union all
    select 'PM130015' union all
    select 'FB3C2' union all
    select 'FB3C2' union all
    select 'PM13001' union all
    select 'PM13001' union all
    select 'PM13002'
) x
order by 
    cast(right(NumberName,PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',reverse(NumberName))-1) as int)
```